# Using multiple languages with routes.php

Tags: codeigniter, url-rewriting

As I'm adding multi-language support to my application and I'm having an issue with my routes.php where certain routes have stopped working.

It seems anything with one segment works, anything with two or more doesn't.

Any help as how to fix this would be much appreciated.

Routes.php excerpt:

```
// URI like '/en/about' -> use controller 'about'
$route['^(en|br)/(.+)$'] = "$2";
$route['dashboard'] = 'dashboard';    //THIS WORKS
$route['profile'] = 'profile/profile_list';
$route['profile_list/page'] = 'profile/profile_list';    //THIS DOESN'T
$route['profile_list/page/(:any)'] = 'profile/profile_list/$1';
$route['profile/update'] = 'profile/update';
$route['profile/(:any)'] = 'profile/$1';
$route['default_controller'] = 'landing';
// '/en', '/de', '/fr' and '/nl' URIs -> use default controller
$route['^(en|br)$'] = $route['default_controller'];
```

Comment: So /en/profile_list/page and /profile_list/page both don't work?

Comment: Yes, it had to do with the number of url segments. I figured out a solution, which I'm going to post.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the answer to this with information from: [Codeigniter forum](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/61150)

Just needed to add this variable, which includes the url segment for any two letter  language code I use:

```
$prepended_lang = "(?:[a-zA-Z]{2}/)?";
```

Then modify the route accordingly:

```
$route[$prepended_lang.'logout'] = 'login/logout';
```